# WebScraping with Java getInputStream(), redirect and umlauts

Tags: java, web-scraping, redirect, diacritics

I have a url `url = new URL("https://website.com/lang/npc="+id);` and want to load the content with `con.getInputStream()` but that results in `Server redirected too many  times (20)`.
This problem is because the website redirects me to a url with umlauts -> `https://website.com/lang/npc=6/koboldgezücht`

How to avoid this problem ?

Comment: What makes you think this has to do with the umlauts?

Comment: because i can access every other page where the redirect has no umlauts. just the pages with umlauts are not working.